# Does it make sense to call async_connect on a unix socket?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using asio to build a network library that can connect to remote systems via TCP or unix sockets. I use `asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket` which has both a `connect` and `async_connect` methods. Does it make sense to use `async_connect` when connecting as a client to a unix socket?

Comment: `connect` and `async_connect` are not interchangeable: working with asynchronous libraries means you will need to restructure the rest of your project code to use asyncronous patterns which can be a significant undertaking. Both TCP and Unix sockets benefit from using asynchronous programming patterns, and Unix socket operations are not inherently synchronous, even if they do happen on the same local machine.

Comment: @Dai but the socket is already there so what do we win by using async_connect?

Comment: @Dai there's absolutely no issue using `boost::asio::connect` on a UNIX domain socket in Asio, regardless of whether the rest of IO will be done using the async operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define "make sense". Both ways work, however with different implications on style, architecture and performance.

Data Input/Output especially over a network has high delays i.e. latency, and lead to the whole fuzzy *async* programming style, boost asio even got its name from.

So using the blocking `connect` would be a very bad choice in the TCP case, since a whole thread is waiting several ms until something happens and can't do anything else, while it would be ok in the case of IPC i.e. unix sockets.

But since you want to both, I recommend to simply use `async_connect`, since you have to organise you whole program in the "async" style for the TCP case anyway, and it doesn't have any drawbacks for the unix socket case (might be also faster or have higher throughput than the blocking one). And to not making unnecessary branches special cases, is considered by many people incl. me as making sense.